# Java export a folder next to jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to make it so, that when I export my project, Eclipse would create .jar file as well as folders and other files I desire on the same path. I am making a game and I rely a lot on external files, be it animation images or scripts, and it is very annoying copy pasting same stuff over and over again, additionally to making the "run" option not viable.

Comment: I would suggest you drop using the Export facility of Eclipse and use a real build tool like Apache Maven or Gradle. Such tools allow easily what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use Eclipse File sync Plugin to solve your problem, basically
>   this plugin synchronizes your eclipse workspace files to any external
>   folder you configured:
>
> FileSync plugin for Eclipse is a file synchronisation tool. The main
>   goal is to keep files outside of Eclipse projects in-sync with Eclipse
>   project files. The plugin works as builder in Eclipse and will
>   synchronize all changes on Eclipse project files with mapped external
>   folders. E.g. if a file is created, changed or deleted in Eclipse,
>   then the mapped (external) file will be created, changed or deleted
>   too.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync